# Clang's UO_AddrOf Unary Operator sensible to overloading of `operator&`

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

It seems that Clang's `UO_AddrOf` unary operator is sensitive to the overloading of `operator&`.

For example, if we have

```cpp
class notapointer {};

struct Bar
{
    inline notapointer operator&()
    {
        return notapointer();
    }
};
```

and E is a clang expression containing an instance of Bar, then

```cpp
Expr* AddrOfE = Sema::BuildUnaryOp(0, loc, UO_AddrOf, E).get();
```

will return an expression of a `notapointer` instance instead of the address the object.

Is there a means to retrieve the actual address instead of following the `operator&` overload?

In a way, it behave like `std::addressof`.

Comment: I *think* you mean "sensitive". It is never sensible to overload that operator.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the question.

Comment: Besides, I think that it is sensible to overload that operator in the context of pointer proxies.

For example `std::vector<bool>` is in fact a bitset. `operator[]` returns a reference proxy, which is a temporary. For `operator->` to make sense on iterators on such containers, you can make it return a temporary pointer proxy with `operator&` overloaded.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is deprecated, and shouldn't be taken as an example of what's sensible.

Comment: Well, it is not really the point of the question here - and std::vector<bool> is a known case of usage of reference proxies that was concise enough for a comment! Overloading `operator&` makes sense for proxies.

Comment: This is interesting, do you have a reference to `std::vector<bool>` being deprecated? I found proposals for it but no actual decisions.